# Set animation for a dynamically created UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I figured out most of the thing how to add UIView dynamically, but now I'm stuck trying to create a alpha animation when a uibutton is clicked and the uiview is shown up. Not sure what I am missing here:

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrIcon.frame.size;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    view.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [scrIcon addSubview:view];


    /*
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    CategoryViewController* theView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryIdentifier"];

    theView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:theView animated:YES];*/

}
```

scrIcon is a UIScrollView

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your code add the view 1st to scrIcon. Then perform the animation.

```
- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrIcon.frame.size;

    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    view.alpha = 0.0f;

    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [scrIcon addSubview:view];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

    view.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];



}
```

Comment: that won't work, view doesn't exist in the context when you are adding the color and as subview to uiscrollview...

Comment: @EdwinSoho please find the updated code.I had missed one line to move up.

Comment: thanks it worked, I will mark it as answered, but Im consufed, how does the runtime know the animation is suppose to be the view and not any other view, If I had it there. Because I can see no reference to view on [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

Comment: what I put between [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; and [UIView commitAnimations]; is what is going to be animated? is that it?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right animation take place between begin & commitAnimation & duration is the time you are look for animation effect. We can play with beginAnimation by passing some valid string & context.This especially used in case of performing different animation on the same view.

Comment: `beginAnimations:context:` has been deprecated for a few iOS versions now. Always use the block-based animation class methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this method: animateWithDuration:animations:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrIcon.frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
view.alpha = 0.0;

[scrIcon addSubview:view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    view.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

In ViewDidLoad: just init Your View…..

```
YourAnimateView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:YourAnimateView];


In Your Button Action Method : just put this

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.1 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                         animations:^{
                             //animation code
                             YourAnimateView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 345);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //completion code

                         }];
```

Comment: Set Your View Frames according to your requirement.. For Temporary i set the frames